# Django 1.6, creating cube data(OLAP) from postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I am not very familiar with OLAP reporting, so is there any django app or python package which converts RDBMS(postgresql) data to cube data, which can be queried using django ORM, I have searched and found solutions like http://cubes.databrewery.org/, jasper etc, but these seemed to be overkill for my use case.

Answer (score 3):

Python Cubes is one of the most lightweight OLAP servers you can find, and it can map your existing relational database into an OLAP schema (without forcing you to transform your data).

In order to query your OLAP cubes, you can use a tool like http://jjmontesl.github.io/cubesviewer/ (disclaimer, I'm the main developer).

Jasper is not really an OLAP server. It's more of a report generation tool.